# DockedSearchBar how to make suggestion list not to push other content?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to have a search view with suggestions in the top app bar. I find DockedSearchBar is a good choice for me. But when it expands and shows suggestions list, it pushes other content down. I want it to draw on top of the content. How can achieve this?

Activity:

```
setContent {
   MyApplicationTheme {
      Surface {
         MainScreen()
      }
   }
}
```

MainScreen:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            SearchView()
        }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = it.calculateTopPadding())){
            Text(text = "Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}
```

SearchView:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var active by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    DockedSearchBar(
        query = text,
        onQueryChange = { text = it },
        onSearch = { active = false },
        active = active,
        onActiveChange = { active = it },
    ) {
        repeat(5) { index ->
            ListItem(
                headlineContent = { Text("index $index") },
                leadingContent = {
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Star, contentDescription = null)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        text = "index $index"
                        active = false
                    }
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
            )
        }
    }


}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom part moves down because once the search bar is opened, the whole view is recomposed and `it` returns new padding values. You could solve your problem by checking the `it`'s padding values:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    var paddingTop = 0.dp

    Scaffold(
        topBar = { SearchView() }
    ) {
        val calculateTopPaddingTop = it.calculateTopPadding()

        if (paddingTop == 0.dp && paddingTop != calculateTopPaddingTop) {
            paddingTop = calculateTopPaddingTop
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(top = paddingTop)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}
```